# Extended interfaces with union type is throwing "property does not exist on type" error. How to fix this?

Tags: typescript

As shown in below screenshots, I have a base interface and i have extended it to create 2 new interfaces with extra fields.

I have aggregated these together as a union type `ChordShapes`

When accessing the field `variant` I get the error as shown in 3rd screenshot.

How to fix this ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the variant field to the base interface too?

Comment: But by IChordShape interface there can't be a variant key. Only Inversion and alternate Bass have variant key. That's what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like TypeScript is preventing me from potentially accessing `variant` on `IChordShape`, which wouldn't exist.
The following changes by using `in` solved the issue :

```
if("variant" in rawShape && rawShape["variant"] === "inversion"){}
```

This is to make sure that the property `variant` does exist before accessing it

OR

Amend `IChordShape` to include `variant: string;` and keep more specific type for `variant` in the extending interfaces so that accessing `rawShape["variant"]` doesn't error out.